# Lightweight migration completed notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've been using lightweight migration for several versions successfully, but in my newest version I need to load some tables that are created during the migration with data after the migration completes. I imagine it's possible that when my initial `UIViewController` calls the method to load data into the new tables, the migration hasn't completed and the app will crash, so:

**How can I determine that lightweight migration has completed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic lightweight migration happens when you call `addPersistentStoreWithType:...`
with the corresponding options, and is completed when that call returns.
There is no asynchronous migration in the background.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is what I thought originally.  I put an NSLog in the else here after calling addPersistentStoreWithType, and the log statement happened hundred of times, so I'm confused why that would happen...ideas?

    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error])
    {
        // Handle the error.
        NSLog(@"Error loading persistent coodinator: %@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Migraton Completed");
    }

Comment: @spotdog13: Well, that is strange. That's a simple if-then-else, so the NSLog can *only* be printed a hundred of times if *you call* addPersistentStoreWithType: a hundred of times ...

Comment: Looks like I've got some debugging to do :)